# Start a job from one server to another server and have it run independent of the first server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a sql server agent job on server1 that runs db backups and uploads them to our backup drive. I want to trigger a package to download and start restoring on server2 when the upload completes. Is there a way to call a job from server1 to server2 and have server2 take over the process so that it runs independently of server1. The point is if server1 fails I want server2 to continue running the downloads.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the sp_start_job command? If you have the job set up in the job agent this should work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15